# Copy Documents In Sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, copy, sharepoint-designer

I don't know enough about Sharepoint to know what to search on, so forgive me if this has been answered a billion times.

I have an aspx page with a half dozen web parts on it (Area1Estimates).  I'd like to create a copy of this (Area2Estimates) and then just go in make some very minor changes to the parameters on the web controls.

I've tried opening the "folder (?)" in sharepoint in explorer view and copying, pasting and renaming the files and have also tried "Send to | Download" and then renaming and uploading.  No matter what I do, when I open the new page it is empty.

I'm using Sharepoint 2007 and trying to do this through the browser.

Whats the correct way to do this?

Thanks
Joe

[edited: clarified situation]

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Designer?  Also, what version of SharePoint is this?

Comment: You might also try posting this on SharePoint.StackExchange.com

Comment: By Web Controls, do you mean "web Parts? Or are you talking about simply moving documents from one library to another?

Comment: Thanks, all.  Updated original message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Site Actions -> Modify all Site Settings -> Content and structure (under site administration). Then you will find a "move" option in a drop down.

Comment: Seems like its almost what I need but I want a copy of it in the same folder -- so http://mysite.com/departments/x/y/x/Area1Estimates.aspx and http://mysite.com/departments/x/y/x/Area2Estimates.aspx

Comment: OK -- That did it.  I created a "drop" folder under the root and copied them there.  I then went into explorer view and renamed the files in /drop and then used the move functionality to put them back where I wanted them.

Comment: Great! This is not intuitive because most times we will look under "View all Site Content" for these kinds of options...